# Looping over a Pandas DataFrame yields a ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, valueerror

I am trying to loop over a Pandas DataFrame with 71163 rows and make a list with values lower than 10000 so that I can count them. So far my code is:

```
filter_heteroSNPs = []

for element in heteroSNPsSC05:  
  if element < 10000:
    filter_heteroSNPs.append(True)
  else:
    filter_heteroSNPs.append(False)

newarr = heteroSNPs[filter_heteroSNPs]

print(filter_heteroSNPs)
print(newarr)
```

But this returns the following exception:

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 71163 instead of 891938
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Please post a snippet of what the data looks like. Hard to help when we don't know what structure `heteroSNPsSC05` is.

Comment: The list only has a single column

Answer (score 0):

Because your iteration is not correct. In which column of your DF, you need to make the comparison?

For example, suppose that you need to compare values from column `'my_column'`, so:

```
filter_heteroSNPs = [True if value < 10000 else False for value in heteroSNPsSC05['my_column']
```

This will give you the filter that you want (even x10 faster)